# jQuery.inArray unable to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is simple but for some reason i am unable to make this work i do not know what i am doing wrong.
anyways the purpose for this code is to give an alert box when the element exists inside the array, names

```
$(doucment).ready(function () {
    var names = ["peter", "John", "mary"];

    if (jQuery.inArray("mary", names)) {
        alert('found');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jfho9f2q/

Comment: Use `jQuery.inArray("mary", names) > -1`

Comment: can i also use `if (jQuery.inArray("mary", names) != ' -1')`

Comment: no.... that string makes no sense especially having a space in it. Indices are numeric, why would you want to compare to string?